# how to import bugsense in Swift

Tags: swift, bugsense

i can find its old implementation that is

```
#import <BugSense-iOS/BugSenseController.h>
```

and

```
[BugSenseController sharedControllerWithBugSenseAPIKey:@"123456" userDictionary:nil sendImmediately:YES]
```

and i am working in the **Swfit** Language

Import doesn't support dash (-)

can anyone update me how to import it in Swift, i also checked it on their [bugsense documentation](https://www.bugsense.com/docs/ios#integration) but couldn't find any updates

Comment: You should also file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com. Tell them there are frameworks with a dash in the name and it breaks. They might just fix it in subsequent beta.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ObjC bridging header help you to import it. First add the framework to your app directory and Xcode will ask you to create the bridging header.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html